# amazon simpledb with aws-sdb-proxy suitable for high traffic production app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-simpledb, activeresource, webrick, amazon-web-services

i am using amazon simpledb with the aws_sdb gem and aws-sdb proxy as outlined in a documentation from amazon with ruby on rails and a local aws proxy that runs on webrick (providing a bridge with ActiveResource).

see http://developer.amazonwebservices.com/connect/entry.jspa?externalID=1242

i am wondering if the aws-sdb-proxy (webrick!) is suitable for high traffic load, since webrick is supposed to be a development server. anyone has comments or experiences?

Answer (score 0):

I've tried Rails with simple_record and I can tell you it's much slower compared to MySQL. You will also have to do quite some work to change your code to adapt to this.

Therefore if you have any high traffic tables that update frequently, I'd say just pass on it. Use MySQL or a different solution. SimpleDB is good only to store metadata for whatever doesn't update very often, and if you get a lot of traffic to that you definitely should get some memcached servers in front of it.

Check this out for some numbers (disregard the Dynamo part of it, I'm now on SDB and moving either back to RDS or Dynamo tonight) [Moving MySQL table to AWS DynamoDB - how to set it up?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16281635/moving-mysql-table-to-aws-dynamodb-how-to-set-it-up)

Comment: Note: sharding won't help. The mechanics they built into that don't help with speed, but rather trade speed for larger capacity by spreading data onto several domains based on a hashing function.